# Hosting multiple sites under root (same hosting account)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a shared hosting account. I need to host a few different websites (basically demo websites) on the same hosting account.

I don't care about domains or subdomains.

So basically what I'm trying to do is:

```
root/
    / website1
    // index.aspx

    / website2
    // index.aspx
    / website3
    // index.aspx
```

etc...

Each website should be accessible by entering: http://example.com/website1/, http://example.com/website2, etc.

But the last time I tried something like this, I kept getting errors along the lines of the website must be in the root directory.

How can this be done?

Comment: where are you hosting them ? Godaddy, bigrock etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see that you are using aspx extension in your files, I will assume that we are talking about ASP.NET.

If they are different websites, with different configurations, it won't work. Different websites need to be hosted in different IIS applications. IIS applications can be created in directories, but shared hosting services usually limit the ability of the user to create new ones (depends on the plan).

Different subdomains should work as different IIS applications. It could be a way to go.